# Throttling an event from a control in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, bing-maps

I have a Silverlight app that utilizes the Bing Maps control. Data loads when ever the maps view stops changing. I saw [an example](http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/dynamically-updating-data-in-bing-maps-v7/) where someone used the ASP.Net version of the control and was able to acheive this. Is this same thing possible in Silverlight?

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addThrottledHandler(map, 'viewchangeend', UpdatePOIData, 250);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rx (unless Im behind) is not yet built into silverlight and seems a little overkill to have the client download all the rx dll just for throttling unless you are going to use it extensively.

At its simplest create your own throttling class using a dispatchtimer which takes the initial call waits x seconds and then checks if another call has come in since before executing your action.

Sorry I dont have any code to hand

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609). The [`Throttle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.throttle%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method exists for this purpose:

```
var observable =
    Observable.FromEventPattern<MapEventArgs>(
        handler => map.ViewChangeEnd += handler,
        handler => map.ViewChangeEnd -= handler);

observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Subscribe(ev => map_ViewChangeEnd(ev.Sender, ev.EventArgs));


...

void map_ViewChangeEnd(object sender, MapEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

(untested)

Comment: Looks interesting; I'll try it today.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the `Invalid cross-thread access ( UnauthorizedAccessExcecption) while using Subscribe function` error you'll get using this code.

Use the following:

```
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<MapEventArgs>(
                    handler => MyMap.ViewChangeEnd += handler,
                    handler => MyMap.ViewChangeEnd -= handler);
observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current).Subscribe(ev => MyMap_ViewChangeEnd(ev.Sender, ev.EventArgs));
```

You have to add the `ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)` to make it work.  And add references for `System.Reactive.Core`, `System.Reactive.Interfaces`, `System.Reactive.Linq` and `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading`.